# Validate input from an array

Tags: java

I'm almost done with this program, I'm just having trouble validating the input.  I need to make sure that the user only uses `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` as the answers, but when I do this my program repeats the end result and doesn't just show `"Only A, B, C, and D are valid"` window. I just need help fixing lines 101-125 in the Exam class (the last code section below).

**The error is in this part**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

if (actionCommand.equals("Exit")){
    System.exit(0);
}
else if (actionCommand.equals("Grade")){
    char[] input = new char[20];
    for (int i= 0; i < input.length; i++){

        input[i] = answerTextFields[i].getText().charAt(0);
        input[i] = Character.toUpperCase(input[i]);
    }
      for (int i=0; i<=input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i] < 'A'|| input[i] > 'D') {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only A, B, C, and D are valid");
            } 
            else {
    driver.setName(nameTextField.getText());
    driver.report(input);
            }
      }    
}        
}
```

Comment: please please please only post the relevant code (I don't think anyone will start to count lines to find what you need help with..)

Comment: what about to make it combo box??

Comment: Can you edit the code part and remove unwanted stuff from it. It is really hard to detect where is it wrong. As you already know where is it causing problem, please past only that part and remove the rest.

Comment: I am unable to get the what are you trying to say by this line - 'but when I do this my program repeats the end result and not just show "Only A, B, C, and D are valid" window.'

Comment: I want it to check if all the answers entered are valid (A, B, C or D) if there exist an invalid answer I want it to display "Only A, B, C, and D are valid" window once, but if it is valid i want it to go directly to the report window which will show if the user passed or failed once. But with the way I have it now it shows the report window every time an answer is wrong and then when it gets to the invalid input it displays "Only A, B, C, and D are valid" window.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want that program should not repeat once the warning message is displayed in Dialog window. I think you need to break from the loop if you dont want the program to repeat after Dialog window is shown. Here is the modified piece of code  :

```
for (int i=0; i<=input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] < 'A'|| input[i] > 'D') {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only A, B, C, and D are valid");
           break; // Added to break the loop
        } 
        else {
driver.setName(nameTextField.getText());
driver.report(input);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        boolean checkValidate = true;
        if (actionCommand.equals("Exit")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (actionCommand.equals("Grade")) {
            char[] input = new char[20];
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

                input[i] = answerTextFields[i].getText().charAt(0);
                input[i] = Character.toUpperCase(input[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
                if (input[i] < 'A' || input[i] > 'D') {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only A, B, C, and D are valid");
                    checkValidate = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

////////////if the user enter wrong answer , it's no need to print the report , so i make the report out For Loop 

            if (checkValidate) {
                driver.setName(nameTextField.getText());
                driver.report(input);
            }


        }
```